# How to add custom style for cast button in cast sdk v3?

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I integrated cast to my app, and the default cast button color is black, but i'd prefer it white.

So I have 2 questions :

1. From what style does it taken from default ?
2. How can i change the style or color of the icon ?

Im using cast sdk v3.

I read the other related posts but they're all relevant to sdk v2.

this is my menu item layout as in google sample :

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

this is the menu code to create the button :

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_podcast, menu);

        mMediaRouteItem =
                CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(),
                        menu,
                        R.id.media_route_menu_item);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple as changing the activity theme to extend Theme.AppCompat instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the [Customize App guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#customize_app) for Castv3 in Android. You can customize the colors, the overlay style, controller style, and more.

Customize Theme

The IntroductoryOverlay class supports various style attributes that your app can override in a custom theme. This example shows how to override the text appearance of both the button and title over the overlay widget:

```
<style name="CustomCastIntroOverlay" parent="CastIntroOverlay">
<item name="castButtonTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Button</item>
<item name="castTitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Title</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Button" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Title" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is only used for customise the other ux widget, e.g the small dialog that opens up when click the button.